# Angular datepicker on a grid within a modal

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, bootstrap-datepicker

AngularJS: date-picker is not working when the control is inside the ngGrid within a modal. It acts as an input text controls as the calendar popup does not popup on focus.

```
$scope.myData = [
      {"id":1,"name": "AAA", "Regdate": "1/10/2012"},
      {"id":2,"name": "BBB", "Regdate": "2/10/2012"},
      {"id":3,"name": "CCC", "Regdate": "3/10/2012"}];

$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  columnDefs:[
        {field:"id",displayName:"ID",width:50},
        {field:"name",displayName:"Name",width:100},
        {field:"Regdate",displayName:"Reg-Date",
        cellTemplate:'<input type="text" ng-model="COL_FIELD" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" datepicker-append-to-body=true />',
        enableCellEdit:true}
    ]
};
```

Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YtRVFegiB6Slj2NtC7ME?p=preview

Suggestions please.

Comment: The calendar popup does not open when focus is on the field

Comment: I added the datepicker on the modal and it works. but does not work when the control is within the ngGrid.  http://plnkr.co/edit/6RvkNQQNJ8oDvWsxUjOz?p=preview

Comment: well, this may be something you need to take to the developers of ngGrid.  without `datepicker-append-to-body=true`, you can somewhat see the top of the datepicker control hiding behind the next cell.  making the cells taller shows more of the datepicker control. The datepicker is clearly confined to the cell, not the outer grid, and is bound by the cell's CSS to not overlap the other rows.

Comment: you can file a bug report here https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/new